# Using controller's method as both endpoint and middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, endpoint

Here are 2 simple scenarios:

1. Get `user` with `id` and return
2. Get `user` with `id`, do some other stuff, and then return

I want to implement scenario `2` as

```
router.post('/api/users/:id/someStuff', controller.getUser, controller.doStuff)
```

But scenario `1` should be implemented as

```
router.post('/api/users/:id/someStuff', controller.getUser)
```

Basically, `controller.getUser` is both a middleware and an endpoint. How do I accomplish this? If I use `res.son()` inside `getUser` and later on reuse it inside `doStuff`, then I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement this as a `app.param` handler for `:userId` and name my param that (there is an example of this in the express docs). Then for scenario 1 the route handler would just do `res.json(req.user);`, and scenario 2 would have `req.user` preloaded for it to do whatever other stuff it needs to do before sending the user. If "send the user" is really just `res.json(req.user)` it's not big enough to factor out into it's own middleware, but if it eventually grew to a snippet of code, you could factor it out to a middleware or a helper function.